# Why is a globally define static variable being reset?

Tags: c++

My code is very large, but I'll try to minimize it here as best as possible.

Basically I want to define a string that is modified in only one place (my main) and then be read in my entire program.

My defines.h is included everywhere so in there I defined.

```
static std::string MAINLOG = "RANDOMNES";
```

In my main function I do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++){

    // Do stuff       

    prepDbugDir();  // This sets MAINLOG to "CORRECT_VALUE"

    std::cout << "Before " << MAINLOG << std::endl;

    // Call a class function whose includes include my defines.h

    std::cout << "After " << MAINLOG << std::endl;


}
```

And the print out of my file is

```
Before CORRECT_VALUE
RANDOMNESS
After CORRECT_VALUE
```

So my question is why and how can I get the value to be maintained inside my classes.

Comment: Did you split your program info several *.a or *.o? it seems that because of your split the programming into several object file, there are several copies of the MAINLOG exist.

Comment: When compiling, yes. If that is the problem, is there a way around this?

Comment: Try putting the declaration of MAINLOG in the header, and the definition only once in a single .cpp file which includes the header (perhaps defines.cpp).

Comment: What happened to `"Before"` and `"After"`? Please post real code.

Comment: Interesting that you didn't get Before or After in the output. I don't think you're really representing what is happening with a mcve.

Comment: use `extern std::string MAINLOG` in the *.cpp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every translation unit (.c or .cpp file, basically) that includes `defines.h` will have its own copy of the variable.

I believe declaring the global `extern` in the header

```
extern std::string MAINLOG;
```

and then defining it as a non-static global variable in any *one* of the .c or .cpp files

```
std::string MAINLOG = "RANDOMNES";
```

will solve the problem. But it's poor coding style, IMO. The C++ way would be at least a singleton class.

I can't give meaningful names without knowing the context, but the idea is as follows:

mainlog.h

```
class Mainlog {
   Mainlog() = default; // Private default constructor

   static Mainlog& instance();

public:
   static const std::string& get() {
      return instance().value;
   }

   static void set(const std::string& newValue) {
      instance().value = newValue;
   }

private:
   std::string value {"RANDOMNESS"};
};
```

mainlog.cpp (don't put this in a header!)

```
Mainlog& Mainlog::instance() {
      static Mainlog mainlog;
      return mainlog;
   }
```

Comment: agree the singleton class is better than global static attribute

Comment: I have a main.cpp and then my classes right. I declared main log as external in my define and in my main (inside my main.cpp), I set it's value. When I do this I get the linker error:  undefined reference to `MAINLOG' where I actually want to read it.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a singleton class?

Comment: @aarelovich.  You have to *declare* the variable in the header file (preceeded with `extern`).  Then you have to *define* the variable in exactly one .cpp file.  This is not the same as setting its value, although you should give it an initial value.  You need to write, in main.cpp, but *outside* any function:  `std::string MAINLOG = "initial value";`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would recommend.

In defines.h:

```
const std::string& mainlog();
```

In main.cpp:

```
const std::string& mainlog() {
  static std::string MAINLOG = "CORRECT_VALUE";
  return MAINLOG;
}
```

Comment: Can't use a const as the value will change multiple times during run.

Comment: But you want to change it in main.  You don't want anyone else to be able to change it, so they get to see a const reference, but not be able to modify it. Also this was the first singleton posted. But you may also return a copy of MAINLOG (just std::string)

Answer (score 1):

Because you put it in your defines.h file, which you then include in your .cpp files, each .cpp file gets its own instance of the string, visible only inside that .cpp file. `static` makes a variable only visible inside the .cpp where it's declared.

Change the static to extern in your defines.h, like this:

`extern std::string MAINLOG;`

Then in one and only one of your .cpp files, add this:

std::string MAINLOG = "RANDOMNES";

That will give you the behavior you expect, but global variables like this are a BAD idea.

Comment: You don't want the initializer on the entry in the header file.

Comment: That is correct. I will fix it. (The joy of cut-and-paste)

Answer (score 1):

When you define a variable with static storage in a header, each translation gets its own unique variable by that name.

A simple fix, if you don't want to go the singleton way, is to declare

```
extern const std::string& MAINLOG;
```

in your header, and then the main file defines

```
std::string MAINLOG_INTERNAL = "RANDOMNESS";
const std::string& MAINLOG = MAINLOG_INTERNAL;
```

This will give you a writeable string that has a read-only "view" in the rest of the program.

Then you can

```
void prepDbugDir()
{
    MAINLOG_INTERNAL = "CORRECTNESS";
}
```

in the main file.